# a word or two, to match the clue

Tags: riddle, word

Find the word(s) and context(s) which satisfy the following conditions.  Note: some of the conditions cannot be met with ease!

> One of us ascends, prior to expulsion.
>   Two of us concealed you before.
>
> One of us, with a preposition, makes a fearsome monster.
>   Two of us make a garment nobody can get himself out of.
>
> If you trade two of us for one of us, you go from beyond ugly to beyond beautiful!

Jason C requested a clarification of the rules.  So, "word" means a word in English.  "Context" may refer to a series of letters that changes one word into another.  For instance, if "laughter" is a word, and "s" is a context, then the clue might be "mayhem" (slaughter).

CLUE:

> Think of "one" and "two" not as quantities, but as indices.

Comment: Is this 3 separate word/context sets or does one set satisfy all of these?

Comment: Also, just to confirm, are you certain that [preposition](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/preposition.htm) is the part of speech you mean?

Comment: Yes, "preposition" is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answers are

> GORGE (one) and HIDE (two).

One of us ascends, prior to expulsion.

> Your GORGE rises shortly before you throw up.

Two of us concealed you before.

> Straightforward definition: HID means CONCEALED and is in the past tense. What's that you say? The word is HIDE not HID? Ah, but this clue is one of those conditions that cannot be met with "E"s.

One of us, with a preposition, makes a fearsome monster.

> GORG/ON. (Another E-less one.)

Two of us make a garment nobody can get himself out of.

> Your HIDE or skin is, in a manner of speaking, a garment you can't get out of.

If you trade two of us for one of us, you go from beyond ugly to beyond beautiful!

> HIDE/OUS -> GORGE/OUS.

Comment: You've got the right words!  Just a little more work on a couple of the clues, and I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Where "a little more work" means "figuring out the two clues I have no idea about at the moment", right? :-)

Comment: (I interpreted "with ease" correctly, I take it?)

Comment: Yeah, you got that right.

Comment: Ah, got one of them (I was expecting them all to be wordplay-y but was wrong). Still confused by the garment, though.

Comment: d'oh, I'm an idiot.

Comment: (all done now.)

Comment: Yeah, you were overthinking that garment thing for a bit  :-)  Nicely done!

Comment: My brain was stuck in wordplay mode for too long.